# How to upgrade to support the post request method? ovh api postman

Tags: api, postman, ovh, postman-pre-request-script

OVHcloud api

postman Pre-request Script

```
pm.sendRequest({
    url: "https://api.ovh.com/1.0/auth/time",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: {}
 },
 function (err, res) {

    pm.expect(err).to.not.be.ok;
    pm.expect(res).to.have.property('code', 200);
    pm.expect(res).to.have.property('status', 'OK');

    var serverTimestamp = res.text();
    postman.setGlobalVariable("lf_ovh_api_app_server_timestamp", serverTimestamp);

    var time_delta = serverTimestamp - Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
    var now = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000) + time_delta;
    var body = '';

    postman.setGlobalVariable("lf_ovh_api_app_timestamp", now);

    var toSign = environment.lf_ovh_api_app_secret + '+' + environment.lf_ovh_api_app_consumer_key + '+' + pm.request.method + '+' + pm.request.url.toString() + '+' + body + '+' + now;

    var signature = '$1$' + CryptoJS.SHA1(toSign);

    postman.setGlobalVariable("lf_ovh_api_app_consumer_signature", signature);
 }
);
```

the "Pre-request" script only supports the GET method for the moment. You are free to upgrade the script to support POST, PUT & DELETE methods.

How to upgrade to support the post request method?

How to upgrade to support the post request method?

Comment: Oh man, are you sure only GET method works in `pm.sendRequest`? Pls, google a bit. e.g https://gist.github.com/gghughunishvili/5672a40eb0830f45839b056f2f517f14

Comment: yes https://laptrinhx.com/work-with-ovh-api-using-postman-91889932/

Comment: the "Pre-request" script only supports the GET method for the moment. You are free to upgrade the script to support POST, PUT & DELETE methods.

Comment: Pls, take a look at my above link, it contains sample of POST request.

Comment: I changed methon to post and still failed,

Comment: Can't help with no information like that. sorry